# Python: how to update several variables/fields dynamically

Tags: python, for-loop, pyqt5

I have several fields (which are changed from time to time) in PyQT5 and I would like to update them dynamically in a for loop. Is there a way of doing this without having to type field by field, like I do for the xDelta variable?

## Example below:

```
x = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'etc']

for i in range(100):
    xDelta = x[i]

    **# I want the rows below to be one row only, updating the "lineEdit_X" dynamically:**

    self.lineEdit_20.setText(xDelta) # instead of x[20]
    self.lineEdit_21.setText(xDelta) # instead of x[21]
    self.lineEdit_22.setText(xDelta) # instead of x[22]
    self.lineEdit_23.setText(xDelta) # instead of x[23]
    self.lineEdit_24.setText(xDelta) # instead of x[24]
```

Thank you

Comment: check `setattr(my_obj, attr_name, 'my_value')`

Comment: You don't even need `setattr` here; consider `y = self.lineEdit_20; y.setText(xDelta)`.

Comment: posted answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47666922/set-properties-of-multiple-qlineedit-using-a-loop

Comment: Strangely (unless I just missed it) no one suggested the most pythonic version of dealing with this and that would be to put each of those LineEdits within a List and then always access them via a subscript because creating self.LineEdit_# is not the way to go at all instead List[#] = QLineEdit('Base Name') this way you can have a dynamic list of QLineEdits instead of a static list of however many you initially started with

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```py
x = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'etc']

for i in range(100):
    xDelta = x[i]

    for widget in centralwidget.children():
        if isinstance(widget, QLineEdit): widget.setText(xDelta)
```

Comment: @juliosouto, did it work?

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

from random import randint

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        centralWidget   = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        timer = QtCore.QTimer(self, interval=1000)
        timer.timeout.connect(self.updateLineEdit)

        button = QPushButton("Start Update")
        button.clicked.connect(timer.start)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(centralWidget)
        layout.addWidget(button)

        self.x = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'etc', '+== abc', '+== def', '+== ghi', '+== jkl', '+== etc']
        self.listLineEdit = []
        n = len(self.x)

        for i in range(n):
            lineEdit = QLineEdit()
            self.listLineEdit.append(lineEdit)
            layout.addWidget(lineEdit)

    def updateLineEdit(self):
        i = randint(0, 9)
        j = randint(0, 9)
        self.listLineEdit[i].setText(self.x[j])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]